# How exe file works

Tags: windows, dos, executable

I am curious about understanding the structure of an exe file and how it gets executed by the operating system, but I can't find much information on the internet. Please suggest me some reading material or links that could explain everything about exe files and how the operating system executes them.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Portable Executable (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable)
- [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EXE) might be a good place to start. After that, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=exe+file+format) may help you find some good sources for reading.